# How to maintain Process Flows in source control?

Tags: process-builder, metadata, version-control

Salesforce appends a version number to the metadata file name. This prevents us from tracking in source control, since Git tracks files by name.

Any good methods of tracking flows in git or other source control?

Answer (score 2):

We use ant to export metadata for some metadata types and automatically push those changes into git (for those metatypes we have flagged as "manual changes" or "prod changes" eg reports being created in prod).

For flows we consider them as "manual changes" IE not checked into git by a developer using eclipse. They get picked up by our ant scripts and the ant script picks the latest flow version and ignores the others and pushes them into git. Its a bit "hacky" but allows us to track changes normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So when you push into git do you strip the version number or just insert newly, so you're tracking the different versions of the same flow as different files in git?